# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:) in ASP.NET 4.6

Tags: c#, url, configuration, asp.net-4.6, validate-request

I'm working on `ASP.NET 4.6` application. I have encountered this exception

```
Exception        :: System.Web.HttpException
    Message          :: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
    Stack Trace      :: 
       at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

I have tried the methods given in the [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=A%20potentially%20dangerous%20Request.Path%20value%20was%20detected%20from%20the%20client%20%28%3A%29) but none worked.

My config:

```
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false" />
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
```

Note: In Request, it allows `;(%3b)` but it blocks `:(%3a)`

Example requests:

- For `;` - `https://www.test.com/te%3b-keyword`
- For `:` - `https://www.test.com/tes%3a-keyword`

Expecting possible solutions other than the [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=A%20potentially%20dangerous%20Request.Path%20value%20was%20detected%20from%20the%20client%20%28%3A%29)

Comment: Try placing the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on the `Controller` method. Also modify your config to include `requestPathInvalidCharacters`: `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Comment: Tried but not worked

Comment: @RahulSharma - Is there anything that i need change from IIS level config?

Comment: You need to install the rewrite module in IIS and then place the rule that you want handle. Else there is a `<rewrite>` section in the web.config where you can add your custom rules to avoid the above scenarion.